# MySQL select statement access part of hex value in column

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table like so:

```
    Type    Col1
    0       ff
    1       9f
    3       92
```

and I want to access just a part of the col1 values

i.e. I want to query the table with a value such as `Col1=92` where all the rows return
and if I queried with `Col1=94` then row 0 and 1 would return and if I queried with `Col1=12` only row 0 would return. Obviously some operation would need to happen on the above assignment statements for this to work.

so something like this:
    `SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE Col1(1)=9;`except I understand that sintax does not work...

hope this makes sense

Comment: why 92 will return rows 0,1,3, 94 only 0 and 1, and 12 just 0?

Comment: I want the `f` to act as a bit mask so all values that would be `AND`'d with it would return that value, however I'm finding that functionality difficult to come by and it's not exactly what I want

Comment: maybe you need something like this? `WHERE HEX(Col1) & HEX('12') = HEX('12')` ?

Comment: if you perform that on row 3 you end up with the result being `true` and I don't want that, `92 & 12 = 12`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least 3 options

first being

```
where `col1` like '9%'
```

second

```
where substr(`col1`,1,1) = "9"
```

Third

```
where left(`col1`, 1) = "9"
```

Comment: thanks! now what if I wanted to reverse it and do it like: 

`where 'col1' like '%2'` 

Would it work simply like that?

Comment: Yes but may be slower due to mysql not being able to use the index, Example 2 will likely be better. But like %2 will work

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that col1 is a text field, you could do:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE col1 LIKE '9%';
```

returns any row where col1 starts with a 9.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html for more "LIKE" patterns

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use substr(string, start, length), so it would be:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE substr(col1,1,1)='9'
```

Comment: I have edited many answers in the past - in this case, I added a new answer, because it is a different answer. Are there guidelines for this? I couldn't find anything in the FAQ